# this.props.history.router doesn't work for the first trigger with websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have a list of item that's rendered using map, then using socket.io a new item is added to the list, I have a click listener on every item.

But have an issue where my `this.props.history.push` is not working during the first click. The page is just not changing, it changed when I trigger it for the second time.

```
console.log(id) //yes it's always present
this.props.history.push(`/job/${id}`)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react router and the route is not been rendered with `<Route />` , you need to wrap your component with `withRouter()` in order to be able to access the `this.props.history.push` read more [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) 
basically `withRouter()` will make history and match and location available for us in the components that **NOT** been rendered by react router!